# Scrollbar height is less that height of div

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow, chakra-ui

### Problem

#### [Editor-1](https://www.dsabyte.com/blogs/write/sa)

Built with

- NextJs
- ReactJs
- Chakra-UI
- Open Source editor

#### [Editor-2](https://example.dsabyte.com/custom-editor)

Built With

- NextJs
- ReactJs
- Open Source editor

> No chakra UI

[Editor-2](https://example.dsabyte.com/custom-editor) has no problem but [Editor-1](https://example.dsabyte.com/custom-editor) has a problem.

### To reproduce

> Paste the below markdown into both editors one by one

```js
# Save your application from crashing by the wrong use of Web Storage API or localStorage in the browser

While coding front-end applications, we may need to store some data on the client side. There are four types of storage on the browser namely cookie, localStorage, sessionStorage and indexDB.

## Github source
see code for 
- [getLocalStorage](https://gist.github.com/ats1999/877f00d4618f091e606bd77fd0a58f8c#file-save-web-storage-js-L2)
- [setLocalStorage](https://gist.github.com/ats1999/877f00d4618f091e606bd77fd0a58f8c#file-save-web-storage-js-L12)
- [isCookie](https://gist.github.com/ats1999/877f00d4618f091e606bd77fd0a58f8c#file-save-web-storage-js-L23)


## What is `Web Storage API`
The Web Storage API provides mechanisms by which browsers can store key/value pairs, in a much more intuitive fashion than using cookies.

<https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API>


***
When you refer to the above-mentioned document, then you'll get the importance of **web storage**.  But do you know that if you are not using it safely, then it'll break your application from further processing? Meaning, if the cookie is blocked, then you won't be able to access `web storage API`, it'll throw an error like below.


// error - when cookie is blocked
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
    at file:///home/rahul/Desktop/projects/test/index.js:1:1


## Let's try
[block-cookie](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+block+cookie&oq=how+to+block+cookie&aqs=chrome..69i57.4096j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> You can refer to the above link to know more about, how can you block cookies. 

**HTML file**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>


**JavaScript file**

// index.js
if(localStorage)
    console.log("local item storage is persent")
console.log("hello")


Now, after blocking the cookie, load the HTML file in a browser. You won't see any information on browser console`(hello), etc`. This is because, once your script encountered an exception, the javascript engine stops further processing. 

In order to avoid crashing the application, we need to wrap the code into `try` and `catch`.


// index.js
try {
    if(localStorage)
        console.log("local item storage is persent")
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
console.log("hello")


Now, you can try the above code. In the above code, exception is handled by the `catch` block. Although, we still can not access `localStorage` this way our application will not crash.

## Do I need to `try/catch` everywhere?
Writing `try/catch` everywhere can be a tedious task. To avoid writing `try/catch`, we can wrap it into another function. 


/**
 * get item from localstorage
 * @param {String} str name of attribte in local storage`
 * @returns item | false
 */
function getLocalStorage(str){
    try {
        return localStorage.getItem(str);
    } catch (error) {
        return false;   
    }
}

// call
getLocalStorage('item');


## conclusion
instead of using `localStorage.getItem(str)` , we should use `getLocalStorage(str)`.

If you liked, then please give a star -> <https://gist.github.com/ats1999/877f00d4618f091e606bd77fd0a58f8c>
## Thanku
```

### Now

Compare the scroll bar of both editors.

#### Editor-1 scroll bar

[image: editor-1]

#### Editor-2 scroll bar

[image: editor-1]

### The Problem

You can see that the **editor-1** scroll bar is ending before the end of the editor. But, the **editor-2** scroll bar is ending at the right position.

> The only difference in both is that editor-1 uses `chakra-ui` as the UI  framework in the entire application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create the desired result by adding a `height: 100%` to the div element (see image).

Here was the update that was made. If you need to use global css, then I'd suggest targeting `.ProseMirror` to add the height property. I simply added inline css using the DOM in Chrome to show what change I made:
[image: Image of dom elements, code changed]

Image before adding in the height property. Notice the gap. Not just with the scrollbar but with the text itself. It doesn't go all the way to the bottom.
[image: before image]

Image after the update, now it looks like Editor 2!
[image: after image]

Comment: hey, it worked fine. But still I would like to know why  it's working in `editor-2` where as its not working in `editor-1`

Comment: I can't say for certain but my gut tells me there's some global styling being applied from Chakra-UI which is affecting the spacing of the elements.

Comment: I think too, this is a big issue with  chakra-ui.